# Worklight ant tasks for deployment

Tags: deployment, ant, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using this [documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Fr_ant_tasks_for_building_and_dep.html).

It tells me to do a ant target like this.

```
<target name="Deploy App"> 
    <app-deployer deployable="${build.apps.dir}/app.wlapp"
        worklightServerHost="http://${customConfig.worklightServer.host}:${customConfig.worklightServer.port}/${customConfig.runtime}" 
        userName="admin" password="admin" />
</target>
```

However when I run this target it tells me that app-deployer task is deprecated and I should use something else.
The entire message is below:

```
[app-deployer] The Ant task <app-deployer> is no longer supported.
[app-deployer] You need to replace this invocation with an invocation of the <wladm> Ant task, like this:
[app-deployer]   <taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/deployers/antlib.xml">
[app-deployer]     <classpath>
[app-deployer]       <pathelement location="buildTools\buildJars\worklight-ant-deployer.jar"/>
[app-deployer]     </classpath>
[app-deployer]   </taskdef>
[app-deployer]   <wladm url="** URL of Worklight administration services **" user="admin" password="admin">
[app-deployer]     <deploy-app runtime="** project runtime name **" file="app.wlapp"/>
[app-deployer]   </wladm>
[app-deployer] where values between ** markers are to be filled in.
```

The version of the worklight ant deployer I'm using is this.

```
 [echo] Worklight Ant task version 6.2.0.00.20140613-0730
```

Nevertheless, when I create a target with wladm it tells me that

```
 Problem: failed to create task or type wladm
 Cause: The name is undefined.
 Action: Check the spelling.
 Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
```

Comment: You forgot the link for the documentation.

Comment: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc%2Fdevref%2Fr_ant_tasks_buld_deploy_adapters.html

Comment: @IdanAdar do you have any comment about this?

Comment: No, you were given comments (answers) below.

Answer (score 2):

The most frequent causes for said error message "failed to create task or type wladm" are:

- The `<taskdef>` has not been executed at this point, in the current Ant script. You may have it in a different target, that is not executed before the current target. The fix is to list it in a common initialization target, or outside of any targets, directory under `<project>`.
- The `<taskdef>` refers to a nonexistent file or to an older version of `worklight-ant-deployer.jar` than 6.2.0.
- The `<taskdef>` loads `resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties"`, but in 6.2 it needs to load `resource="com/worklight/ant/deployers/antlib.xml"`.

Comment: Thanks! Actually here http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc%2Fdevref%2Fr_ant_tasks_buld_deploy_adapters.html tells us to load resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties" I'll try now your solution. What I find weird is that it finds the app-deployer task and tells it's deprecated, offers a solution and then it doesn't find the solution offered. ???

Comment: Changing the resource didn't work. It told me:
The following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/C:/Users/xpto/workspaceLuna/worklightapp/buildTools/buildJars/worklight-ant-builder.jar!/com/worklight/ant/deployers/antlib.xml:23: taskdef class com.ibm.worklight.admin.ant.WladmTask cannot be found
 using the classloader AntClassLoader[C:\Users\xpto\workspaceLuna\worklightapp\buildTools\buildJars\worklight-ant-builder.jar] build.xml /worklightapp/buildTools line 67 Ant Buildfile Problem

Comment: You need to use worklight-ant-deployer.jar instead of worklight-ant-builder.jar. Or, if you attempt to use both in the same Ant script, follow this recipe to resolve the conflict: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_for_building.html?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to your question but if you do not need Ant, you can use wladm in command line. See doc at https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/admin/r_wladm_program_app_commands.html

The wladm command is in [WorklightInstallDir]/shortcuts

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to script a automatic build and deploy task for my app. Since IBM documentation tells me that this is possible, I'm trying to not resorting to that.